# Upload com $http post

Tags: angularjs, upload

No meu controlador, tenho o seguinte código que utilizo para fazer POST do meu formulário:

```
 $http.post(url, json_object).then(function (results) {
     console.log(results.data);
 });
```

O código acima envia para o servidor um json.

Como adapta-lo para fazer upload de imagens?

Comment: Eu estou utilizando uma versão desta library para file upload utilizando $resource: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

Como você deve ter percebido, o Angular por padrão faz POST com o `Content-Type: application/json`.

Para alterar o comportamento, é necessário construir um `FormData` e instruir o Angular a não alterar o conteúdo dos parâmetros enviados na requisição POST.

Isso tudo pode ser feito com o seguinte código:

```
// insira este código aonde for apropriado (controller, service, etc)
this.upload = function () {
    var t = this; // preguiça de escrever this
    var promise = null;

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("image", t.image);
    form.append("description", t.description);

    promise = $http.post("/api/1/images", form, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": undefined // remove o content-type
        },
        transformRequest: angular.identity // não transforma os parâmetros
    });
    promise.success(function (data, status) {
        alert("Uhuuulll!!!");
    });
    promise.error(function (data, status) {
        alert("Wow =/ " + data);
    });
};
```

Repare que neste código, além da imagem, eu envio também uma descrição dela. Ou seja, tal qual em uma requisição POST sem Angular (tal qual a gerada pelo browser em um `form` sem Angular), pode-se enviar dados "não binários", ou até várias imagens, se preferir.

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias bibliotecas prontas em angular para isto, entre elas:

- https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/
- https://github.com/leon/angular-upload
- https://github.com/uor/angular-file
- https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload
- https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload
- https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare

Recomendo que analise as opções e escolha a que melhor se adapta ao seu caso.

Comment: Essa pesquisa eu fiz no google antes de criar a pergunta. O que eu quero é adaptar o que eu tenho e não utilizar algo pronto, mas obrigado pela ajuda.